# Count elements in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, plyr

I have a data frame like this :

```
      ID                          TYPE
  100010700239816                932100Y
  100010700239816                9DDDDDDY
  100010700239822                0000000000011222211121110100000000000000Y
```

The output should be like this :

```
    ID                9   3   2   1   0   Y   D
 100010700239816      2   1   1   1   2   2   6
 100010700239822      0   0   5   9   11  1   0
```

So this is just a sample data, there could be different elements inside a single cell and count of all of those elements is what I am looking for.

I have tried :

```
 a <- count(TEST$TYPE)
```

and

```
 a <- table(TEST$TYPE)
```

But I am not able to get the counts of the elements for id's, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the 'TYPE', grouped by 'ID' and `dcast` into 'wide' format

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1)[, unlist(strsplit(TYPE, "")) , ID], ID ~V1)
```

Comment: Hello @akrun , I am getting an error in strsplit(TYPE," ") , it says object 'TYPE' not found. :/

Comment: Probably have to convert the data.frame to a data.table beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use the functions from `tidyverse`. We can `strsplit` the string, `unnest` the string and `count` the numbers of each string-ID combination. Finally, we can `spread` the data frame to get the desired output (`dt2`).

```
dt <- read.table(text = "     ID                          TYPE
  100010700239816                932100Y
                 100010700239816                9DDDDDDY
                 100010700239822                0000000000011222211121110100000000000000Y",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(TYPE = strsplit(TYPE, "")) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  count(ID, TYPE) %>%
  spread(TYPE, n, fill = 0) %>%
  select(c("ID", "9", "3", "2", "1", "0", "Y", "D"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go with `stringr`

```
df2 <- aggregate(TYPE ~  ID, data=df, FUN=paste, collapse='')
df2[, unique(unlist(strsplit(df2$TYPE, "")))] <- 0
library(stringr)
df2[, unique(unlist(strsplit(df2$TYPE, "")))] <- sapply(colnames(df2[, unique(unlist(strsplit(df2$TYPE, "")))]), 
                                                      function(i) str_count(df2$TYPE, i))
```